# Should 企 be pronunciated as ㄑㄧˋ or ㄑㄧˇ?

Tags: pronunciation

It seems that different online dictionaries gave me different answers:

[image: Here it reads]

[image]

Is 企 a heteronym?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no.

If you check out [Liang'an](https://www.moedict.tw/~%E4%BC%81) you'll see it mentions:

> qì

and

> [陸] qǐ

So basically what that tells us is: Mainland (i.e.: PRC) is qǐ, while Taiwan is qì.

It's a regional -or- topolectical thing, rather than a character with different pronunciations at different times.

Comment: Thank you! It is interesting that there are several characters that are pronounced differently in PRC and ROC.